# PHP replace a row in csv works fine on my localhost but does not replace the row when uploaded to cpanel?

Tags: php, cpanel

Hello I am relatively new  to PHP and I was trying to replace a row in a csv file, i didnt find an optimal solution so I concocted script (a work around) which suits my needs for the time being till I grasp a better understanding of PHP

I tested it on my localhost using XAMPP and everything was working fine , it was replacing the row as intended but when i uploaded the files to my cpanel it stopped replacing and instead it just goes the normal route and write the row on new line.

this is my code :

```
$fileName = 'Usecase.csv'; //This is the CSV file 
$tempName = 'temp.csv';     
$inFile = fopen($fileName, 'r');
$outFile =  fopen($tempName,'w');
while (($line = fgetcsv($inFile)) !== FALSE) 
{
    if(($line[0] == "$fin") )   //Here I am checking the value of the variable to see if same value exists in the array then i am replacing the array which will be later written into the csv file 
    {
        $line = explode (",", "$tempstr10"); 
        $asd=$asd+1; //this is the variable that i defined and assigned value 0 in the top most section, this is used later in the code 
    } 
    fputcsv($outFile, $line );
}
fclose($inFile);
fclose($outFile);
unlink($fileName);

rename($tempName, $fileName);
    if( $asd==0  && filesize("Usecase.csv")>0) // here its checking if the value is 0 , if value is 0 then that means the above code didnt execute which means the value wasnt present in the file , this is to avoid writing the same string again into the file 
    { file_put_contents("Usecase.csv", "$tempstr10\r\n",FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX); } 
 
    if( $asd==0  && filesize("Usecase.csv")==0)
    { file_put_contents("Usecase.csv", "$tempstr10\r\n",FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX); }
```

and as I mentioned above , its working on the localhost but not on the cpanel , can someone point out if something is wrong with the code ? or if its something else ?
thank you

Answer (score 1):

The most likely problem is that your local version of PHP or your local configuration of PHP is different from what is on the server.

For example, `fopen` is a feature that can be disabled on some shared servers.

You can check this by creating a php file with the following conents:

```
<?php phpinfo();
```

Then visit that PHP file in your browser. Do this for both your local dev environment and your cPanel server to compare the configuration to identify the differences that may be contributing to the differing behavior.

You should also check the error logs. They can be found in multiple different places depending on how your hosting provider has things configured. If you can't find them, you'll need  to ask your hosting provider to know for sure where the error logs are.

Typical locations are:

- The "Errors" icon in cPanel
- A file named "error_log" in one of the folders of your site. Via ssh or the Terminal icon in cPanel you can use  this command to find those files: `find $PWD -name error_log`
- If your server is configured to use PHP-FPM, the php error log is located  at `~/logs/yourdomain_tld.php.error.log`

You should also consider turning on error reporting for the script by putting this at the very top. Please note that this should only be used temporarily while you are actively debugging the application. Leaving this kind of debugging output on could expose details about your application that may invite additional security risks.

```
<?php
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

... Your code here ...
```

Comment: `ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);` is of no-use at the beginning of a script in PHP, as, when executing this line, PHP has already passed the start-up phase and the setting is ineffective. And I would recommend - if you allow me the additional comment - to put a note at that place that this should be only done temporarily and must be removed after trouble-shooting, as leaving it in would cause error messages to be displayed to regular website visitors which are not the audience of such diagnostic messages.

Comment: @hakre Thanks for the heads up! I've added a note about using the debug output only temporarily. However, (and this a genuine question, not sarcasm) is it not  possible for non-fatal startup errors to occur that would still appear after the script has finished executing? The documentation is not clear about this, but I noticed that the setting is a PHP_INI_ALL configuration. The fact that you can place it within a script via ini_set suggests that it may have utility there. Do you have any reference for the claim that it serves no purpose within the script itsself?

Comment: _"is it not possible for non-fatal startup errors to occur that would still appear after the script has finished executing?"_ not that I'm aware of. Startup is before the script begins. _"I noticed that the setting is a PHP_INI_ALL configuration"_ This means it can be set everywhere, incl. in a script where it makes not much sense as too late (startup is over, errors in startup won't be displayed if they haven't been displayed yet). _"Do you have any reference for the claim that it serves no purpose within the script itsself?"_ I have practically verified it now with the CLI SAPI.

Comment: > `php -n -d extension=xxx -r 'ini_set("display_errors", "1"); ini_set("display_startup_errors", "1");' 2>/dev/null` vs. > `php -n -d extension=xxx -d display_startup_errors=1 -r 'ini_set("display_errors", "1"); ini_set("display_startup_errors", "1");' 2>/dev/null`

Comment: Thanks for checking that out @hakre, I very much appreciate it when a bit of effort and expertise can verify those nuggets of wisdom. I've updated the error reporting config to remove that line.